# multiplicative operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-equations, semigroup-of-operators

The following Functional Equation $$f(x+y+xy)=f(x)+f(y)+f(x)f(y)$$ is called Pompeiu Functional Equation. The solution to this equation is the Pompeiu Function given by $$f(x)=M(x+1)-1$$ where M is multiplicative, i.e, $$M(xy)=M(x)M(y)$$ where $x,y\in R$ .

What I am looking for is an operator analogue of $M$, that is, are there any bounded linear operators that satisfy the multiplicative property as defined above? Do such operators exist in literature? If they do, are they elements of ${Z(t)}_{t>0}$ where ${Z(t)}_{t>0}$ denotes $C_0$- semigroups.

Comment: The only linear operators that are also multiplicative are the zero and identity operators.

Comment: On the other hand, you can talk about linear operators being infinitesimal generators of multiplicative operators, but I'm not sure if you're looking for that kind of thing.